# Função média no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatação

Preciso inserir a função média no excel em intervalos. Por exemplo, de A1:A5, logo após de A6:A10, A11:15 e assim por diante. Como faço para que o excel entenda essa lógica?

Pensei em fazer com que ele entenda que o intervalo anterior deve ser alterado em 5 unidades. Exemplo:

A(1+5):A(5+5), porém esse tipo de programação não é permitido.É bom enfatizar que desejo fazer isso sem que eu precise mesclar as células para cálculo da média, pois no exemplo ilustrado é de pequeno porte, mas para o que desejo aplicar é inviável ficar mesclando células equivalentes aos valores que desejo obter a média.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui o que eu queria.

Por exemplo média para um intervalo de A1:A5, depois disso, A6:10 e assim por diante, podemos assim utilizar a fórmula:

=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW(A1)-1)*5,0,5))

Comment: No caso, basta fazermos um preenchimento automático posteriormente a isso.

Answer (score 0):

Tudo bem?

Acredito que o código abaixo pode ajudar.

Eu fiz com base na planilha que você mostrou acima.

Basicamente, ele soma os valores da coluna A:A de acordo com o intervalo estipulado na célula "E3". Depois que a soma é feita, é feita a divisão pelo número no intervalo estipulado (ou seja, calcula uma média simples).

Esse cálculo é feito até a última linha preenchida, porém se o intervalo ultrapassar a lista de valores e, com isso, forem selecionadas células vazias no intervalo de cálculo, as células preenchidas serão consideradas como valor zero, o que afeta o cálculo da média.

A planilha que eu usei para teste ficou assim:

[image: Cálculo]

E o código é esse:

```
Private Sub btCalcular_Click()

Dim W           As Worksheet
Dim A           As Integer
Dim B           As Integer
Dim C           As Integer
Dim UltCel      As Range
Dim Intervalo   As Integer
Dim Soma        As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declara e seleciona a aba em que serão feitos os cálculos
Set W = Planilha1
W.Select

'Encontra a última linha preenchida
Set UltCel = W.Cells(W.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

'Recebe o intervalo de células para cálculo das médias
Intervalo = W.Range("E3").Value

A = 2
B = 2
C = 2
Soma = 0

'Apaga as médias preenchidas antes
W.Range("E1:XFD1").ClearContents

W.Range("E1").Select

'Calcula as médias até a última linha preenchida e insere os valores nas células do campo "Médias"
Do While A <= UltCel.Row

    Do While B <= Intervalo + 1
    
        Soma = Soma + W.Range("A" & C).Value
    
        C = C + 1
        B = B + 1
    
    Loop
    
    ActiveCell.Value = (Soma / Intervalo)
    
    A = A + Intervalo
    'Intervalo = Intervalo + Intervalo
    B = 2
    C = A
    Soma = 0
    
    'Pula uma célula para o lado para incluir a próxima média
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

Loop

'Apaga as variáveis
Set W = Nothing
Set UltCel = Nothing
A = Empty
Intervalo = Empty
Soma = Empty

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Feito!"

End Sub
```

Qualquer coisa, chame aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar a seguinte fórmula para evitar o uso da função offset (volátil), que é executada sempre que haja uma qualquer alteração na folha Excel.
=AVERAGE(INDEX($A:$A,(ROW(A1)-1)*5+1,1):INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1)*5,1))
ou
=AVERAGE(INDEX($A$1:$A$100,(ROW(A1)-1)*5+1,1):INDEX($A$1:$A$100,ROW(A1)*5,1))